# Mt. 22:39: "like" or "equal"?

Tags: greek, matthew, latin-vulgate, peshitta, syriac

[7:33 ff. of this sermion](https://youtu.be/DfgPqFV59Nw?t=453) says that an alternative translation of [Mt. 22:39](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=47&ch=22&l=39-#x) is: "the second [commandment] is *equal* (not "like") to this: Thou shalt love thy neighbour as thyself." No [English translations of Mt. 22:39](https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/Matthew%2022:39) (except perhaps the NLT: "A second is equally important: …") say this.

Does the Syriac say "equal"? The Greek uses [ομοία](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?la=greek&l=%CE%BF%CE%BC%CE%BF%CE%AF%CE%B1) (could this sometimes mean "equal"?). St. Jerome's Latin uses [*simile*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?la=la&l=simile#lexicon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Aramaic/Syriac/Hebrew/Greek/Latin scriptural scholar friend wrote:

> The expression used originally in Aramaic by Our Blessed Lord explaining these two interrelated commandments is typical of a Hebraic
> formula often recurring in the Scriptures, which tends to be “lost” in
> translations.
>
> איך נפשך… ←
>
> I certainly would not say that “like” is a defective translation
> relative to “equal,” since איך in Aramaic is nothing other than a
> comparative preposition, meaning precisely “like” or “as.”
>
> But it is also true that to compare here, as when saying x is like y,
> in no way lessens the true meaning of the divine commandment as it
> pertains to the love of one’s neighbor, quite to the contrary. What
> follows the comparative preposition איך, in Aramaic, makes the case
> powerfully compelling and clear, since we find the term נפשא, meaning
> “soul,” with the possessive determiner at the end, giving נפשך,
> meaning “thy soul” (rather than just “yourself”).
>
> Thus, the Aramaic portion of the text of Matt 22:39 we are discussing
> here quite literally translates as follows:
>
> “Thou shalt love thy neighbor as/like your [own] soul.”
>
> This is where the pertinence of “equal” comes into play, both in
> relation to loving God, the first commandment, and to loving our
> neighbor, the second commandment, and so no less than loving our own
> very soul (we sure need grace). And this, I believe, we most
> especially do whenever we do what we can for the eternal welfare of
> anyone (their temporal welfare included), blood relative or not,
> friend or enemy.

Comment: Your answering your own question as the right answer when the answer doesn't answer at all. It doesn't mean equal it means "like". It goes (something) like this.

Answer (score 1):

The OP essentially asks about two similar but still distinct Greek words as follows:

- **ὅμοιος (homoios)** = "like, resembling, similar to, etc".  It occurs 45 times in the NT, eg, Matt 11:16, 13:31, 33, 44, 45, 20:1, 22:39, Luke 6:47, 48, 7:31, 12:36, 13:18, etc.
- ἴσος (isos) = "equal, equivalent, identical".  It occurs eight times in the NT, Matt 20:12, Mark 14:56, 59, Luke 6:34, John 5:18, Acts 11:17, Phil 2:6, Rev 21:16.

> Matt 22:29 (BLB) - And the second is like it: 'You shall love your
> neighbor as yourself.'

In Matt 22:39, Jesus compares the two greatest commandments of the Torah - the greatest being the Shema in Deut 6:4, 5, but the second was "similar".  Note that Jesus did NOT say the second was equal or identical because that would mean that our love to God was just as important as our love to fellow humans - in fact Jesus specifically says that our love to God MUST surpass all others.  (Luke 14:26)

Thus, in Matt 22:39, Jesus was saying that the second great commandment is similar but certainly NOT equal to the command to love God supremely.

Barnes has a similar suggestion:

> The second is like unto it - Leviticus 19:18. That is, it resembles it
> in importance, dignity, purity, and usefulness.

Similarly, the Pulpit commentary:

> **Like unto it**; ὁμοία αὐτῇ: in nature and extent, of universal obligation, pure and unselfish.